# Using and updating textfiles as data storage

Tags: vb.net

I am not too sure why, but the current stock for all the items now appears as zero when it shows up in a listbox/on the 'receipt'. Also, I am struggling to get it to update back up from zero when it becomes zero.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim GTIN As String
    Dim LineContaining As String
    Dim quantity As String
    Dim description As String
    Dim singleamount As String
    Dim singleprice As Double
    Dim totalprices As Double
    Dim correctcode As Boolean
    Dim stocklevel As String
    Dim requiredstock As Integer
    Dim remainingstock As Integer
    Dim stock As Integer
    'declare variables
    Private Sub btnEnterGTIN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterGTIN.Click
        GTIN = getValidGTIN()
        Call itemfinder(GTIN)
    End Sub
    Function getValidGTIN()
        Dim GTIN, ValidGTINAmountCharacters As String
        Dim GTINOK As Boolean
        'Declaring variables.
        GTINOK = False
        Do
            GTIN = InputBox("Enter the full GTIN Number (it should be 8 digits long)")
            'Prompts the user to enter the GTIN.
            ValidGTINAmountCharacters = Len(GTIN)
            'Makes it so that the amount of characters of the GTIN is stored in the variable ValidGTINAmountCharacters.
            If ValidGTINAmountCharacters = 8 Then GTINOK = True
            'Makes it so the program will only accept an input if it was 8 characters long.
            If Not IsNumeric(GTIN) Then GTINOK = False
            'Makes it so that if any other character typed in apart from a number is not valid.
            If Not GTINOK Then MsgBox("The GTIN Number isn't valid. It should be a 8 digit number. (Should not contain letters or symbols).")
            'Makes it so that if the GTIN is not valid according to the above, a message appears saying it is invalid.
        Loop Until GTINOK
        Return GTIN
    End Function
    Private Sub itemfinder(ByVal GTIN As String)
        Using reader As New IO.StreamReader("receipt_orders.txt")
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                If line.Contains(GTIN) Then
                    LineContaining = line
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End Using
        'reads the textfile to find the entered GTIN
        description = Mid$(LineContaining, 10, 17)
        singleamount = Mid$(LineContaining, 38, 4)
        stocklevel = Mid$(LineContaining, 43, 2)
        quantity = InputBox("Enter the quantity you require?")
        'prompts user to input the quantity


        Dim QuantityOK As Boolean
        QuantityOK = False
        If quantity <= stocklevel Then
            QuantityOK = True
        End If

        Dim GTINOK As Boolean
        GTINOK = False
        Using reader As New IO.StreamReader("receipt_orders.txt")
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                If line.Contains(GTIN) Then
                    GTINOK = True
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End Using
        stocklevel = stock
        If QuantityOK = False And stock > 0 Then
            MsgBox("There is not enough of this item in stock, restocking item to extra stock needed. You will not get " _
                   & quantity & " items, but we can give you " & stocklevel & " and restock the remaining amount.")
            requiredstock = quantity - stocklevel
            totalprices = stocklevel * singleamount
            lstGTIN.Items.Add(GTIN)
            lstName.Items.Add(description)
            lstQuantity.Items.Add(quantity)
            lstInStock.Items.Add(stocklevel)
            lstAdditionalStock.Items.Add(requiredstock)
            lstSinglePrice.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(singleamount))
            lstTotal.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(totalprices))
            lstTotals.Items.Add(totalprices)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("GTIN Code: " & GTIN)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Item: " & description)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Quantity wanted: " & quantity)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Quantity available: " & stocklevel)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Required restock amount: " & requiredstock)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Price per unit: " & FormatCurrency(singleamount))
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Subtotal cost: " & FormatCurrency(totalprices))
        End If

        If QuantityOK = False And stock = 0 Then
            MsgBox("This item is out of stock. We will register this item for restock in time for your next purchase.")
            requiredstock = quantity
            totalprices = 0
            lstGTIN.Items.Add(GTIN)
            description = Mid$(LineContaining, 10, 17)
            lstName.Items.Add(description)
            lstQuantity.Items.Add(quantity)
            lstInStock.Items.Add(stocklevel)
            lstAdditionalStock.Items.Add(requiredstock)
            lstSinglePrice.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(0))
            lstTotal.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(totalprices))
            lstTotals.Items.Add(totalprices)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("GTIN Code: " & GTIN)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Item: " & description)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Quantity wanted: " & quantity)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Quantity available: " & stocklevel)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Required restock amount: " & requiredstock)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Price per unit: " & FormatCurrency(0))
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Subtotal cost: " & FormatCurrency(totalprices))
        End If
        'if the GTIN is found in the textfile it is valid.

        'if the GTIN code was incorrect then put the listboxes as product not found or zero.
        If QuantityOK = True Then
            MsgBox("No restock of item needed.")
            totalprices = quantity * singleamount
            remainingstock = stocklevel - quantity
            lstGTIN.Items.Add(GTIN)
            lstName.Items.Add(description)
            lstQuantity.Items.Add(quantity)
            lstInStock.Items.Add(stocklevel)
            lstAdditionalStock.Items.Add(requiredstock)
            lstSinglePrice.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(singleamount))
            lstTotal.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(totalprices))
            lstTotals.Items.Add(totalprices)
            'if the GTIN code was correct, calculate the subtotal amount and put information in listboxes.
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("GTIN Code: " & GTIN)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Item: " & description)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Quantity: " & quantity)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Quantity in stock: " & stocklevel)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Required restock amount: " & requiredstock)
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Price per unit: " & FormatCurrency(singleamount))
            lstReceipt.Items.Add("Subtotal cost: " & FormatCurrency(totalprices))
            'adds all the information onto a receipt - updates after every purchase.
            Dim contents As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("receipt_orders.txt")

            If GTINOK = False Then
                lstReceipt.Items.Add("GTIN Code: " & GTIN)
                lstReceipt.Items.Add("Item: Product not found")
                lstGTIN.Items.Add(GTIN)
                lstName.Items.Add("Product not found!")
                lstQuantity.Items.Add(0)
                lstSinglePrice.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(0))
                lstInStock.Items.Add(0)
                lstAdditionalStock.Items.Add(0)
                lstTotal.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(0))
                lstTotals.Items.Add(0)
            End If

            contents = contents.Replace(stocklevel, remainingstock)
            IO.File.WriteAllText("items_to_restock", contents)

        End If


        Dim totalprice As Double
        For x As Integer = 0 To lstTotals.Items.Count - 1
            totalprice += Val(lstTotals.Items.Item(x).ToString)
        Next
        'adds up the numbers in the total list box and puts in the text box TotalPrice.
        txtTotalPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(totalprice.ToString)
        'formats the total as a currency.
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        'clears all listboxes
        lstGTIN.Items.Clear()
        lstName.Items.Clear()
        lstQuantity.Items.Clear()
        lstSinglePrice.Items.Clear()
        lstTotal.Items.Clear()
        lstTotals.Items.Clear()
        lstReceipt.Items.Clear()
        lstInStock.Items.Clear()
        lstAdditionalStock.Items.Clear()
        'clears the total text box
        txtTotalPrice.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShowCodes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowCodes.Click
        Process.Start("receipt_orders.txt")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but is way to much code to understand what your problem really this. Please provide a more clear description and only post the code that is involved in the problem. Describe what you have tried and where you're stuck at the moment

Comment: Start by adding `Option Strict On` at the top of the file

Comment: You're using strings to hold numbers and then comparing them etc. You won't get mathematical results. Use integers for quantity, stocklevel etc. and as Plutonix says turn on `Option Strict On`